# PhantomJS page loading fails for URL with query string

Tags: phantomjs

I am opening a local html file with PhantomJS 2.1.1.  I would like to pass a value to the page using a query string.

Here is my code:

```
var args = require('system').args;
args.forEach(function(arg, i) 
{
    console.log(i+'::'+arg);
});

var page = require('webpage').create();
page.viewportSize = { width: 1000, height: 800 };

page.onConsoleMessage = function(msg)
{
  console.log(msg);
}

//var postBody = 'dataLoc='+args[2];
//page.open('///'+args[1], 'POST', postBody, function(status)

//page.open('///'+args[1]+'?dataLoc='+args[2], function(status)
page.open('///'+args[1], function(status)
{
    console.log("Status: " + status);

    var url = page.url;
    console.log('URL: ' + url);

    var clipRect = page.evaluate(function()
    {
       return document.querySelector("div#map").getBoundingClientRect();
    });
});
```

I have left commented-out lines to show what I have tried.  Opening the page with a passed-in argument of the page file name works (this is the one not commented out).  Opening the page as a POST works, but the query string is not available on the page when I look at window.location.search.  Opening the page with the query string as part of the URL fails outright.  If I open the URL with the query string directly in the browser, then I see it in window.location.search when I log to the console.

The error I get on the console when I try to put the query string directly in the url is this:

```
C:\phantomjs-2.1.1-windows\bin>phantomjs.exe .\public\openPagePhantomJS.js c:/phantomjs-2.1.1-windows/bin/public/testHeatMap.html testParam
0::.\public\openPagePhantomJS.js
1::c:/phantomjs-2.1.1-windows/bin/public/testHeatMap.html
2::testParam
Status: fail
URL:
ERROR: TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'document.querySelector("div#map").getBoundingClientRect')
TRACE:
 -> undefined: 2
 -> : 3

  phantomjs://code/openPagePhantomJS.js:49 in onError
```

So, the page is never actually loaded at all.  If you made it this far, thanks.  Any pointers for me?  My experience level with PhantomJS is low.

Comment: Try to console.log the url you're opening, could there be a typo?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Vaviloff, but the url is fine.

Comment: Try adding `file:` at the beginning of your URL

Comment: paps, that's it!  Thank you so much